# Remove Azure Virtual Machine from Scale Set

Tags: azure

I have configured an Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set with Health Extension. The scale is set to 1 (manual scale).

At some point, the Instance may shutdown.

While automatic repair is enabled, Azure leaves the instances shutdown instead of starting a new instance.

Is it possible to automatically remove a VM from the set if it is shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't try to match Azure and aws they both have their own standards and best practices

If you reduce your scale set capacity from 20 to 15% here is how the VM are being removed

By default, virtual machines are removed from the scale set evenly across availability zones (if the scale set is deployed in zonal configuration) and fault domains, to maximize availability. VMs with the highest IDs are removed first.
You can change the order of virtual machine removal by specifying a scale-in policy for the scale set.

---

Otherwise you need to create some automation using an automation runbook or a logic app